# Protection against tampered user input and SQL injection fails

Tags: php

So I have a form with 2 text inputs.
One is price and the other is quantity.
Before saving the form there are some checks that act as safeguard against tampered user input and SQL injection.

so one of them is:

```
    if(strval(floatval($quantity)) === $quantity && strval(floatval($price)) === price) {
      $errors = false;
   }
```

The problem with this check is that if we have $price = "47.80" for example 
floatval() gives us 47.8 and then strval() gives us "47.8" which does not equal to "47.80"
So the check fails and we get an error.

I would like to know if you can think of a way to go around this without changing the logic too much.

Comment: Why this? If your quantity is integer - check if it is integer. If your price is float - check if it's float. For string-represented numerics there are such things as `is_numeric()`, for instance. But really: [this](http://us1.php.net/filter_var) and [this](http://us1.php.net/ctype)

Comment: The real solution is to use  prepared statements and not have to worry about sql injection.

Comment: It's not a float. It is actually a string coming from database. And it's also stored as a string. Plus the input is a textbox with a string value anyway. This is the way the form is and like I said I don't want to change that for various reasons. So I have to find a way to manipulate it.

Comment: @AlmaDo I will try out is_numeric(), it might do the trick here. Thanks! You can post it as a proper answer if you'd like. Sive numeric strings is indeed the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter extension:

```
$price = filter_var($price, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

It removes everything that is not a digit or a period.

If the number has to have two decimal points then you have to somehow enforce that. You can either not allow numbers without two decimal points or you can fix the input yourself. Something like this should do:

```
$price= number_format($price, 2, '.', null);
```